# How can I auto-generate the repositoryClass docbloc with orm:convert:mapping?

Tags: php, doctrine

I can generate entities from the database using the following command:

```
php doctrine.php orm:convert:mapping --namespace="App\Entity" --from-database annotation src/App/Entity
```

However, in order to be able to run the `orm:generate-repositories` command, I need to add the following *manually* to the top of each generated Entity:

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\User")
```

*(Note: `@ORM\Entity` already exists on it's own here.)*

The docs make no mention as to the ability to have this repositoryClass automatically added for you. Is it possible to have this done automatically, maybe via some hidden argument or configuration variable?

Comment: you might be able to set it up using a yaml mapping: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html search for repositoryClass I have not tried

Comment: This is not something supported right now. Also, importing mappings from DB is supposed to be used only once, and only when importing a legacy DB